# How to get the column name of the CANDIDATE Keys through jdbc?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, foreign-keys, unique-constraint, notnull

I need to find candidate keys of a table. As for a column to be a candidate key,
it must be (1) NOT NULL and (2) UNIQUE. So what I am doing is:

```
   for(i=1;i<colcount; i++){
       if( (resultset.getmetadata().isnullable(i)==0) && (UNIQUE_COND) ){
            // IS A CANDIDATE KEY
       }
   }
```

How can I check for UNIQUE condition? I am using mysql db through JDBC.
Is there another way to get candidate keys?
Thanks.

Comment: HELP? I need to submit my project asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `DatabaseMetaData`, not the metadata of the resultset. Specifically you need to look at:

- [getPrimaryKeys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getPrimaryKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [getIndexInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getIndexInfo%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) with parameter `unique` set to true.